# How do i get the navbar to be like a navbar as shown in the picture?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, i am doing this frontend mentor challenge. I have done the mobile first design. My problem is how do i get my navbar to be like this [image: Expected Navbar] . I have tried using display flex with flex direction row but the mobile design navbar is not changing its shape and size.

My code is producing the navbar like this [image: Using media query : min width 768px]

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong in the media query that i am not getting the output i desire.

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/572b4fce3c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Shortly URL shortening API Challenge</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->

</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <section class="header">
      <!-------- Header Section -------->
      <nav>
        <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
        <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
          <!-- <i class="fa fa-solid fa-xmark"></i> -->
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showHideMenu()"></i>
      </nav>
      <img class='illustration' src="/images/illustration-working.svg" alt="illustration">
      <div class="first-section-content">
        <h1>More than just <span class="short">shorter links</span></h1>
        <p>Build your brand's recognition and get detailed insights on how your links are
          performing.</p>
        <button class="get-started">Get Started</button>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- URL shortening -->
    <article class="shorten-details">
      <section class="shorten">
        <div class="shorten-link">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Shorten a link here....">
        </div>
        <span class="error-msg">Please add a link</span>
        <button class="short-it">Shorten It!</button>
      </section>
    </article>

    <!-- URL Copy -->
    <article class="url-copy">
      <div class="hide-url">
        <section class="copying-url">
          <p class="given-link">https://www.linkedin.com/</p>
          <hr>
          <div class="return-links">
            <p class="small-link"><a href="" target="_blank">shrtco.de/8RPDKD</a></p>
            <button class="copy">Copy</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      </section>
      <!-- <div class="hide-url">
        <section class="copying-url">
          <p class="given-link">https://www.linkedin.com/</p>
          <hr>
          <div class="return-links">
            <p class="small-link"><a href="" target="_blank">shrtco.de/8RPDKD</a></p>
            <button class="copy">Copy</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      </section>
      <div class="hide-url">
        <section class="copying-url">
          <p class="given-link">https://www.linkedin.com/</p>
          <hr>
          <div class="return-links">
            <p class="small-link"><a href="" target="_blank">shrtco.de/8RPDKD</a></p>
            <button class="copy">Copy</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      </section> -->

      <section class="advanced-stats">
        <h2>Advanced Statistics</h2>
        <p class="perform">Track how your links are performing across the web with our advanced statistics
          dashboard.</p>
        <div class="stats">
          <div class="stat">
            <img class="brand-img" src="/images/icon-brand-recognition.svg" alt="brand-recognition">
            <h3>Brand Recognition</h3>
            <p class="stat-desc">Boost your brand recognition with each click. Generic links don’t mean a thing.
              Branded links help instil confidence in your content.</ class="boost">
          </div>
          <div class="stat-1">
            <img class="brand-img" src="/images/icon-detailed-records.svg" alt="detailed-records">
            <h3>Detailed Records</h3>
            <p class="stat-desc">Gain insights into who is clicking your links. Knowing when and where people
              engage with your content helps inform better decisions.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="stat-2">
            <img class="brand-img" src="/images/icon-fully-customizable.svg" alt="fully-customizable">
            <h3>Fully Customizable</h3>
            <p class="stat-desc">Improve brand awareness and content discoverability through customizable
              links, supercharging audience engagement.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>

    <article class="boost-links">
      <section class="boost">
        <h2>Boost your links today</h2>
        <button class="get-started-2">Get Started</button>
      </section>
    </article>

    <article class="last-footer">
      <section class="footer">
        <div class="footer-links">
          <div class="footer-link">
            <h2>Shortly</h2>
            <h3>Features</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Link Shortening</li>
              <li>Branded Links</li>
              <li>Analytics</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-link">
            <h3>Resources</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Blog</li>
              <li>Developers</li>
              <li>Support</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-link">
            <h3>Company</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>About</li>
              <li>Our Team</li>
              <li>Careers</li>
              <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="socials">
          <div class="social-icons">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </main>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>.
    Coded by <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/nelson-uprety-951a2b156/">Nelson Uprety</a>.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code for the header / navbar part:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500;700&display=swap');
  @import url('css-reset.css');

  :root {
      --color-cyan: hsl(180, 66%, 49%);
      --color-dark-violet: hsl(257, 27%, 26%);
      --color-red: hsl(0, 87%, 67%);
      --color-gray: hsl(0, 0%, 75%);
      --color-grayish-violet: hsl(257, 7%, 63%);
      --color-grayish-violet-op: hsl(257, 7%, 63%, 0.3);
      --color-very-dark-blue: hsl(255, 11%, 22%);
      --color-very-dark-violet: hsl(260, 8%, 14%);
      --color-second-bg: hsl(230, 25%, 95%);
      --color-white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
      --font-weight-five: 500;
      --font-weight-seven: 700;
  }

  body {
      font-family: 'Poppins',
          sans-serif;
  }

  main {
      overflow: hidden;
      /* border: 1px solid green; */
      max-width: 390px;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }

  /* -------Header Section--------- */

  .header {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 30px;
      max-width: 350px;
  }

  .nav {
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
  }

  .nav-links {
      background-color: var(--color-dark-violet);
      width: 330px;
      height: 370px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      transition: 0.3s;
      top: 100px;
      right: 63px;
      visibility: hidden;
  }

  nav .fa {
      display: block;
      color: var(--color-grayish-violet);
      font-size: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      right: 63px;
      top: 30px;
      position: absolute;
  }

  .nav-links ul li {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 14px;
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
  }

  .nav-links ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: var(--color-white);
      font-weight: var(--font-weight-seven);
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      padding: 10px 100px;
      border-radius: 25px;
  }

  .nav-links ul li a:hover {
      background-color: var(--color-cyan);
      color: var(--color-white);
  }

  .nav-links ul li:nth-child(3) {
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-grayish-violet-op);
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

  .illustration {
      position: relative;
      right: -50px;
      transform: scale(1.6);
      margin-top: 100px;
      right: -90px;
      z-index: 1;
      display: block;

  }

  .first-section-content {
      margin-top: 100px;
      transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .first-section-content.menu-open {
      margin-top: 130px;
      transition: 0.3s;
  }


  .first-section-content h1 {
      font-size: 2.67rem;
      font-weight: var(--font-weight-seven);
      color: var(--color-very-dark-blue);
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      margin-left: 9px;
      width: 350px;
      line-height: 1.2;
  }

  .short {
      margin-left: 15px;
  }

  .first-section-content p {
      font-size: 1rem;
      color: var(--color-grayish-violet);
      font-weight: var(--font-weight-five);
      margin-bottom: 35px;
      margin-left: 6px;
      width: 350px;
      line-height: 2;
      letter-spacing: 0.7px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }

  .get-started {
      background-color: var(--color-cyan);
      color: var(--color-white);
      border: none;
      padding: 14px;
      font-weight: var(--font-weight-seven);
      width: 190px;
      border-radius: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-left: 70px;
  }

  @media (min-width:768px) {
      body {
          overflow-y: scroll;
          min-height: 100vh;
          overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      main {
          height: 100vh;
          max-width: 100%;
          overflow: scroll;
      }

      .header {
          display: flex;
          /* align-items: center; */
          /* flex-direction: row; */
          width: 100%;
      }

      nav {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          align-items: center;
          gap: 2.3rem;
          padding: 2.9rem 9.2rem;
          position: relative;
      }

      .nav-links {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          width: 100%;
          justify-content: space-between;
      }


      .nav-links ul li {}

      .nav-links ul li a {
          display: flex;
          display: inline;
          flex-direction: row;
          background-color: transparent;
          visibility: visible;
          color: var(--color-gray);
      }

      nav .fa {
          display: none;
      }



  }
```

Comment: One of the main rules of  a *flexbox container* is that its mechanism applies **only one level deep**. What is your main *flexbox* container? How many levels deep is the `ul` and its `li`? What is the default direction of a *flexbox container*, what of the `ul`? How many logical parts does the example navbar have? How many did your define in your HTML? As this is a challenge, I'm not going to post code, but just ask a few questions to get you thinking...

Comment: @RenevanderLende this really got me thinking. I am figuring out all the things that you have mentioned. Thank you

Comment: @RenevanderLende can you please help me with this problem. Thank you

Comment: As Johannes already answered: your `.navlinks ul` needs to be a *flexbox* row parent container. He told you **what** to do, I told you to think about **why**. Check your `@media` query for `.nav-link ul { .. }`. What does it do? Right, it's not there... As stated before, I'm not going to post any code (check my SO profile, it will give you an idea why I am such a pain).

Answer (score 1):

`display: flex;` needs to be on the `ul` inside the `.nav-links` div - that `ul` is the element which contains the navigation items.